# Why is the returned ResultSet null

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Given this Table Structure:

[image]

I want to get basic details of a user from a database, so 
I created a `ResulSet` named `rst` (see code below). 
When I iterate over `rst` it always returns `null`.

```
public ResultSet Detail(String mobile) throws Exception {
    dbConnect(); // make connection 
    String sql = "select * from profile where mobile = ?";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1, mobile);
    ResultSet rst = pstmt.executeQuery();
    dbClose(); // connection closed
    return rst;
}
```

Now if I iterate over `rst` after having received it from return, I get the `null` value.

```
try {
    ResultSet rst = new DB().Detail(mobile);
    String fname = rst.getString("firstname");
    String lname = rst.getString("lasttname");
    String date = rst.getString("dateofbirth");
    System.out.println("First name : " + fname + "\nLast Name : " + lname + "\nDate of Birth : " + date);
} catch (Exception exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
First name : null
Last name : null
Date of Birth : null
```

Comment: Just one thing to follow the Java code style guidelines: You should rename the `Detail(String mobile)` method to `getDetail(String mobile)`, as Java method names should always start with a lowercase letter and usually with a verb, for example `get` (getter methods), `set` (setter methods) or `is` (boolean getter methods).

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation of [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) you need to call the `next()` method *before* you can access the data elements from the ResultSet:

> A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

This is missing in your posted code fragment. Therefore, your code fragment no. 2 should be written as follows:

```
try {
     ResultSet rst = new DB().Detail(mobile);
     if(rst.next()) {
         String fname = rst.getString("firstname");
         String lname = rst.getString("lasttname");
         String date = rst.getString("dateofbirth");
         System.out.println("First name : " + fname + "\nLast Name : " + lname + "\nDate of Birth : " + date);
     } else {
         System.out.println("No data for the given parameter '" + mobile + "'");
     } 
} catch (Exception exc) {
     exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

As noted in the comment/answer by Jalal Kiswani, it's also recommendable to NOT close the DB-connection before you're finished processing the `ResultSet`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the database connection will cause to close all related objects (resultset and prepared statement). so rs will not be valid after `dbClose();`
You should read the result set before closing the connection.

Comment: Based on the assumption that `java.sql.Connection#close()` is actually called in the implementation of `dbClose()` which we are not presented in the OP... ;)

Comment: If you are not closing the connection ,prepapred statement or resultset in `dbClose()`, you should follow MWiesner answer by calling `if(rs.next())`  before reading the record.

Comment: Actually, your should follow both advices of both answers.